# Is there any good software to correct scanner defects?

Tags: software-recommendation, scanner, image-processing

I have an old scanner that apparently has some defects. When I connected it to my Linux laptop and scanned a white A4 paper I got this.

[image: Linux Scanned White Paper]

But with Windows Fax and Scan I got this which is almost okay.

[image: Windows Scanned White Paper]

Somehow Windows Fax and Scan managed to correct the scanner defects. But going to Windows just to scan some documents is annoying. Is there a tool for Linux that can correct this kind of defect?

Comment: What scanner do you have?

Comment: CanoScan LiDE 700f

Comment: What does it look like if you scan an image or some text in linux?

Comment: Yellow stripes show up like in  the above image.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Vuescan](https://www.hamrick.com) a try. It's a nice multi platform scan software, that works with a lot of different devices.

Comment: Free version of Vuescan adds watermark.  I hope there is a free alternative.